# install laravel/ui with auth in non fresh laravel

Tags: laravel, npm-install, laravel-7

I have non refresh Laravel project that upgraded it to 6 then 7 and now i want to install laravel ui auth by this document.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

after:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

and after installing:

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

and then:

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

here i have error:

```
 10% building 1/1 modules 0 active
webpack is watching the files…

 98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                                       1:09:33 PM

 error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'outputStyle'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:96:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:301:20
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:73:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)

 error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'outputStyle'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:96:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)

 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253

     Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/js/app.js  1.38 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'outputStyle'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\xampp\htdocs\****************-server\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:96:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\xampp\htdocs\*****************-server\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:301:20
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:73:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.sc
ss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'outputStyle'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:96:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\xampp\htdocs\***************-server\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253
```

so i need solution,

i cant resolve this sass package error.

Answer (score 0):

resolved by uninstall then reinstall

```
npm uninstall --save-dev sass-loader
npm install --save-dev sass-loader@7.1.0
```